# Start Firefox from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, firefox, command-line

I am trying to create a batch file which starts Firefox, and prints "Firefox started" on the screen. I had to use the "start" command so that my batch file doesn't stop running after Firefox is started.

```
@start "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
@echo Firefox started.
@pause
```

Instead a command line of Firefox is started. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
echo Firefox have started.
...Do something else here...
pause
```

If you want to be a little fancier, echo to a cscript which will popup a windows, where you have to click <kbd>Ok</kbd>, before the batch file will continue to the next command.

```
@echo off
echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > DisplayMsg.vbs
echo messageText = objArgs(0) >> DisplayMsg.vbs
echo MsgBox messageText >> DisplayMsg.vbs

start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
timeout /t 3
cscript DisplayMsg.vbs "Firefox has Started successfully!"

...Do something else here...
pause
```

for more on the actual starting of firefox, do `start /?` from commandline for help. You have however used `@` before your commands, which actually turns echo off.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
start "Firefox!" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
echo Firefox started.
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

The first quoted argument in a `start` becomes the window title. Insert a dummy quoted argument (the content is irrelevant) and all should be well.

Using an `@echo off` statement means that the `@` doesn't need to be used in following lines. The `@` says "don't echo this command". `@echo off` means "turn off echoing" (which can be turned on again by `echo on`) - the `@` in `@echo off` means "don't echo the ECHO OFF statement"